# How to load file JS and CSS using herbert, enqueue

Tags: wordpress, herbert

I'm following the example of the official website.

```
$enqueue->front([
    'as'     => 'vueJS',
    'src'    => Helper::assetUrl('/js/vue.js')
]);
```

And I need it to load in a view, I use the example of the official page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Profesores</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ content }}</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I use a controller to load the view

```
public function getProfesores()
{
    $profesores = Profesor::all();
    return view('@MyPlugin/profesores/lista.twig', [
        'title'   => 'My Demo',
        'content' => 'Congrats on your demo view.',
        'data'=> json_response($profesores->toArray())
    ]);

}
```

Maybe it's easy but it does not work for me, can someone help me?